# unable to call an appengine module service

Tags: google-app-engine, module, gae-module

I have a simple appengine application with two modules (default, and module - I know it is not a great name for a module...).
If I understood the naming convention I should be able to address services exposed on the 'module' module with the following http address:

```
https://module.<appid>.appspot.com
```

When I try to call my service with this address I get a connection time out exception.
When I use the the following api from within the default module modulesApi.getModuleHostname("module", null), I get "1.module..appspot.com".
Is that right? Shouldn't the api return just module..appspot.com, I guess by qualifying the name with the a instance we give up load balancing...
Anyway if I try to connect to:

```
https://1.module.<appid>.appspot.com
```

I get connection timeout as well.

What should I do be able to connect to a service exposed by a module?

Here is my configuration:
I use java, and the 1.8.8 appengine SDK.
My service is a jax-rs rest service created with jersey. I can see from the log that the service is correctly initialized during the module warm up.
I'm not using appengine Endpoints nor  Task queues.

In a previous version of my application I had only a webapp with the service in it and everything worked correctly. So I'm pretty sure the service code and configuration is right and that the problem depend on the migration to the module architecture.

Thanks
Raffaele

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a configuration problem on my client. Once I solve that problem I found another one. Apparently Google certificates don't support double wild cards, so they don't support host name in the form of A.B.appspot.com. The way around it is to use another naming convention. In the end I had to use the following address to connect: https://module-dot-<appid>.appspot.com